# How to get the project type of MVC 6 project?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-extensions, asp.net-core-mvc, vsix, vs-extensibility

I'm using a context menu for MVC projects. I'm using  value of the project to enable the add-in. For MVC3,MVC4 and MVC5 its working fine. But MVC 6 (ASP.NET 5) project doesnt have  value in the project file (.xproj) and also I cant get the  value using the method GetAggregateProjectTypeGuids() which can be used for older MVC projects. Is there any other way to find the project type? I need to find whether the project is MVC6 or not to change the add-in visibility.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as an MVC 6 project. There's a project with a dependency on MVC 6. If you want to check you need to look at the package references.